# PaddleOCR ValueError

Tags: python, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I trained the Paddle detection model with my own custom data.

I have exported it and converted it to the required model format using the command:

```
python3 tools/export_model.py -c configs/det/det_r50_vd_db.yml -o Global.pretrained_model="./output/det_r50_vd/latest" Global.save_inference_dir="./output/det_db_inference/"
```

Following was the output:

```
W0804 12:55:34.817917 4102 gpu_resources.cc:61] Please NOTE: device: 0, GPU Compute Capability: 6.0, Driver API Version: 11.0, Runtime API
Version: 10.2
W0804 12:55:34.822103 4102 gpu_resources.cc:91] device: 0, cuDNN Version: 7.6.
[2022/08/04 12:55:35] ppocr INFO: load pretrain successful from ./output/det_r50_vd/best_accuracy
[2022/08/04 12:55:38] ppocr INFO: inference model is saved to ./output/det_db_inference/inference
```

Then I have tried to run the inference using the following:

```
python3 tools/infer/predict_det.py --det_algorithm="DB" --det_model_dir="./output/det_db_inference/" --image_dir="../image"
--use_gpu=True
```

However, I get a ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tools/infer/predict_det.py", line 262, in
text_detector = TextDetector(args)
File "tools/infer/predict_det.py", line 121, in init
args, 'det', logger)
File "/home/user/paddle/PaddleOCR/tools/infer/utility.py", line 317, in create_predictor
predictor = inference.create_predictor(config)
ValueError: (InvalidArgument) The inverse of Fused batch norm variance should be finite. Found nonfinite values! Please check batch_norm_55.w_2
[Hint: Expected std::isfinite(variance_array[i]) == true, but received std::isfinite(variance_array[i]):0 != true:1.] (at /paddle/paddle/fluid/framework/ir/conv_bn_fuse_pass.cc:105)
```

Can anybody help me what does this issue mean and why it might be arising?

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: (InvalidArgument) The inverse of Fused batch norm variance should be finite.

The guess is that your model training time is too short, resulting in the parameter value of BN being infite.
It is recommended to train it longer or select a model with higher accuracy model to export the inference model